# Is this how I should use 'on_guild_join' in discord.py?

Tags: python, sqlite, discord.py

I am planning to make a bot for running PvP-based TRPG game, and so, for every new game, I was planning to make a new discord server for that. As it would be too tedious to set the stage for it, (make 5 new channels, 4+(number of players) new roles, and set those to work as intended and so on) I searched for the way to bot to do it and found out 'on_guild_join' event listener might be useful.

As I don't know all about discord.py, I managed to build part of the sequence I know, but some parts missing. Can someone help me fill out the parts that I left as a comment?

```
@Cog.listener()
    async def on_guild_join(self, guild):
        db.execute('INSERT INTO war_guild (GuildID) VALUES (?)', self.guild.id) # Is self.guild.id in here can get GuildID?
        guild = db.record('SELECT GuildID FROM war_guild', *)
        channel_id = #get channel id from only text channel that is created when the new channel is formed.
        db.execute('INSERT INTO channels VALUES (staff-room, ?)', channel_id)
        channel_name = ['server-gateway', 'random-chatroom', 'gameplay-map', 'cemetary', 'log']
        for chan in channel_name:
            await ctx.create_text_channel(chan)
            channel_id = #channel id that has been created from the line before
            db.execute('INSERT INTO channels VALUES (?,?)', chan, channel_id)
        role_name = ['GM', 'Player', 'Ghost', 'Spectator']
        for rol in role_name:
            await ctx.create_role(name=rol)
            role_id = #role id that has been created from the line before
            db.execute('INSERT INTO roles VALUES (?,?)', rol, role_id)
        # Set role permission and channel permission
```

and, as I don't know exactly how to use 'on_guild_join', I don't think my placement of this part is good enough to get the codes below it working. I'll give the pastebin link of my codes that I think might be better place to put it, if the title is its corresponding place, which place will it be better?

my code pastebin links:

lib\db\__init__.py: https://pastebin.com/H5rMyHkC

lib\db\db.py: https://pastebin.com/KKyQNf3R

lib\bot\__init__.py: https://pastebin.com/FYK14uHt

launcher.py: https://pastebin.com/arT4v6YJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into the [Permissions class](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=permissions#discord.Permissions) (for the list of the permission flags name) and the coroutine method of [discord.TextChannel](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=channel%20permissions#discord.TextChannel) [set_permissions](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=channel%20permissions#discord.TextChannel.set_permissions) that takes a Member or a Role as target, and the permissions

So it would look like this :

```
    @Cog.listener()
    async def on_guild_join(self, guild):
        db.execute('INSERT INTO war_guild (GuildID) VALUES (?)', self.guild.id) # Is self.guild.id in here can get GuildID?
        guild = db.record('SELECT GuildID FROM war_guild', *)
        channel_id = #get channel id from only text channel that is created when the new channel is formed.
        db.execute('INSERT INTO channels VALUES (staff-room, ?)', channel_id)
        channel_name = ['server-gateway', 'random-chatroom', 'gameplay-map', 'cemetary', 'log']
        channels = []
        roles = []
        for chan in channel_name:
            channels.append(await ctx.create_text_channel(chan))
            db.execute('INSERT INTO channels VALUES (?,?)', chan, channels[-1].id)
        role_name = ['GM', 'Player', 'Ghost', 'Spectator']
        for rol in role_name:
            roles.append(await ctx.create_role(name=rol))
            await roles[-1].edit(permissions=Permissions(Permissions.read_messages, Permissions.send_messages)
            db.execute('INSERT INTO roles VALUES (?,?)', rol, roles[-1].id)
        for chan in channels:  # chan is a TextChannel object
            for rol in roles:
                await chan.set_permissions(rol, read_messages=True, send_messages=False)
```

the method to create roles, sending messages, creating channels, etc always return the created object and it is very useful. For the last loop I added, you should change the read_messages=True, send_messages=False, ... to any permission you want, and you can use [role.name](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=role%20name#discord.Role.name) to discriminate between all the roles in the `for rol in roles` loop, as can also be done for the channels via [channel.name](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=channel%20name#discord.abc.GuildChannel.name)

Also, you could simply once you have the role that is created, immediately set its permissions to what you want via a permission list with the same order as your channel_name or role_name list.

I don't think the last loop for changing the permission of each channel for each role is necessary, you should be able to do everything you need by setting each role with its permission via [role.edit](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=role%20permission#discord.Role.edit)